# Is Christianity SE turning into a forum?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me, Christianity SE is going away from being a Q&A, and being "I don't like what this is asking, so I'm going to down vote it and vote to close it"... It doesn't seem like any of the other stack exchanges, and it's unlike them in a BAD way... So is this a prevailing opinion?

Comment: Downvoted since it doesn't seem to me like it is becoming a forum.  I simply haven't observed the problems you are describing.

Answer (score 9):

Question closure and downvoting are things that *separate* us from forums. They are our tools to control the quality of posts that are coming through and help us maintain a high quality, civil, SE site.

What you're noticing is *not* the result of too many of these, but not enough. We need far more users downvoting and voting to close than we currently have. I cannot tell you how many posts I happen upon days after they are posted that are not anywhere close to our quality standards, are broken windows ripe for tripe answers that don't have a *single close vote*. We need a lot more people voting to close.

Please use your flags, familiarize yourself with our quality guidelines and start taking aim at the drivel you see coming through.

Comment: I may agree with that over on rpg SE, but from what I've seen on this SE, if people see something they don't like, but are according to guidelines, people down vote and vote to close...

Comment: @ZeDemonPyro it happens a bit here, but remember that there isn't really anything everyone agrees with here. Our *best* subjects here are VoP Monks over there.

Comment: take a look at my question here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/why-did-christians-begin-to-celebrate-other-religions-holidays ... Closed for "unclear what I was asking"... It was at no point in time unclear... And look at the highest voted answer... It shows just an opinion, and no research into the matter...

Comment: @ZeDemonPyro yeah, that's probably the wrong close reason. I don't disagree with the closure though, you're asking a very broad question with probably at least 10 possible correct answers. One of the things we see a lot here is that people ask questions expecting there to be a single "This is what Christians did/do/believe/practice", when there isn't a monolithic Christian answer to many things at all. Why to Christians celebrate easter? Depends on the church, Why Christmas? Again, depends on the church. Some don't, some do for reason A, some do for reason B....etc. Try narrowing it down.

Comment: I wasn't involved in the vote, but I know that VTC for unclear what you are asking is often used if it isn't defined well enough to be answerable.  It does make it very close to "too broad", but in general "too broad" could be answered but has a book.  I normally see "unclear what you are asking" as being used when there are multiple possible contradictory answers as the question is currently phrased.  Personally, I think it is probably too broad even with further specification, but there is no ability to get a "correct" answer without further scoping of the question.

Answer (score 4):

> It doesn't seem like any of the other stack exchanges, and it's unlike them in a BAD way...

Christianity.SE *is* like all the other SE sites: I see meta questions like this on every SE site where I'm active, basically claiming that other sites don't downvote and close as much.

The insistence on strict Q and A (not discussions) along with voting is what makes SE sites better than a forum.

I can't cast close votes here, but I think "Unclear what you're asking" is fair since you made it clear what you think the answer is, so it seems like you mostly want people to discuss that point of view.